# Использование возможностей cURL в Java

Tags: веб-сервер, android, java

Для тестирования работы сервера использую cURL, с помощью этой команды:

curl -H "TOKEN_NAME: TOKEN_VALUE" https://.../assets.json?max_id=-1

,где я указываю имя токена и его значение для доступа к json. Ответ приходит верный.
В Java(Android) пробовал многими способами, в итоге возвращает только html, с ошибкой.
Вот один из использованных способов:

```
private void sendPost3() throws Exception {
    Log.d("test", "------------------sendPost3------------------------");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost();

    // add header
    post.setHeader(TOKEN_NAME,  TOKEN_VALUE);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_VALUE));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    post.setURI(new URI(mUrl));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    for(Header h : post.getAllHeaders()) {
        Log.d("test", "header = " + h.getName() + h.getValue());
    }

    Log.d("test", "\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + mUrl);
    Log.d("test", "Post parameters : " + post.getEntity().toString());
    Log.d("test", "Response Code : " +
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    Log.d("test", result.toString());
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cURL`'ом вы шлёте `GET`-запрос, а из `Java`-кода — `POST`.

Comment: Действительно. А я где то прочитал, что нужно post и get даже не и не думал использовать=) спасибо большое за ответ! Заменил HttpPost на HttpGet и все, не пойму только в чем разница, заголовок мы в обоих случаях передаем, наверное в post он передается в теле, и по этому не был прочитан.